# repo sync failed (fetch error) not solved even with -f -jn command

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I get this error in `repo sync`:

```
error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

then I use this command:`repo sync -f -j1`but steal getting same error,then I use `repo sync -j1 -f --force-sync` and it has same result and next I type those commands :

```
repo sync --force-sync system/core
repo sync --force-sync
```

but there was no change too ,please help me to solve that.
thank you.

Comment: nobody khnows??

Comment: What `repo init`  command are you using ?

Comment: hello, this init command : repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

Comment: @Hugoy oh, I forgot to say that I used this init command too :                         repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1

Comment: please answer my question if you know. I really need that.

Comment: I tried last night and it worked fine. Do you have a stable internet connection ?

Comment: @Hugoy  I'm using openvpn but my connection is stable